# Fix problem in php line of code $sql = SELECT item FROM table WHERE user = $user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that includes a `$sql = SELECT FROM WHERE = $variable` query. The query should produce a JSON list of `itemids` linked to a `userid` in a `usersitems` table. When I hard code the `userID` the query works but when I use the `$variable` the query `$Result` is `No Records`.

I have rewritten the script code and tried various punctuation variations numerous times. No joy.

```php
//A missing prior code block establishes connection with database.

    $userID = $_POST["userID"];

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully". "<br>";
      //below testing that $userID holds correct value
    echo $userID. "<br>";

    //Below is commented line to test hard coded userID value.
    //$sql = "SELECT itemID FROM usersitems WHERE userID = '1' ";

    //Here's the SELECT line that's driving me batty.
    $sql = "SELECT itemID FROM usersitems WHERE userID = '" . $userID ."'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // output data of each row
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($rows);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No records.";
    }
    $conn->close();
```

If I use a hard coded userID value (in place of the $userID) then the script works and I get the json output expected.  When I use the $userID I get a No Records result.

Comment: Is the user ID getting echo'd correctly from this line `echo $userID. "<br>";`?

Comment: Yup.  The echo $userID line displays the correct userID number in the console.

Comment: It's probably because there is something else in `$userID` apart from the actual ID (Like a space, newline or similar). Since it's numerical, it actually shouldn't be quoted. Additionally your code is susceptible to MySQL injection attacks, which is a very serious security issue. I suggest reading up on it. You can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1106272

Comment: I'll examine closely the $userID to see if there's something that shouldn't be in it, and get rid of the quotes.  I also will look at the links re MySQL injection, as well as comments and formatting.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: You were right about there being extra characters in the $userID.  I was able to determine the set of characters and got rid of it with the code below.

Comment: @SteenSchütt:  you were right about extra characters in $userID.
I found extra characters in www.downloadHandler.text, specifically "Connected successfully<br>".
I first tried to comment out every "Connected successfully<br>" in my C# and php code but when I ran my code the characters still appeared in www.downloadHandler.text.
Next thing I tried, which worked, was to strip out the characters with the code below.

string result = www.downloadHandler.text;
string newUserID = result.Replace("Connected successfully<br>", "");
Main.Instance.UserInfo.SetID(newUserID);
Debug.Log(newUserID);

Comment: @atymic, It might be helpful to mention that my php, and C# code, is being done with a Unity game engine frontend.  This should explain the Main.Instance.User.SetID(newUserID) line of code.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You need to use prepared statements to ensure that malformed SQL cannot be passed via the `$userID` variable.

Please see: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

I've updated your code to use a prepared statement, which should work correctly.

```php
<?php

$userID = trim($_POST["userID"]);

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully". "<br>";
//below testing that $userID holds correct value
echo $userID. "<br>";

//Below is commented line to test hard coded userID value.
//$sql = "SELECT itemID FROM usersitems WHERE userID = '1' ";

//Here's the SELECT line that's driving me batty.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT itemID FROM usersitems WHERE userID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $userID);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    // output data of each row
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);
}
else
{
    echo "No records.";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the point you're trying to make is, that the sanitization will fix the input variable (In addition to fixing the SQL injection vuln). If that is the case, that could be explained in more detail.

Comment: `$result->num_rows` is completely redundant and the while loop could be replaced with`fetchAll`

Comment: Much thanks for the code to fix the SQL injection problem.  I'll work on implementing it in my coding.

Comment: @atymic: Much thanks for the code to fix the SQL injection problem.  I'll work on implementing it in my code.